# using oracle sql substr to get last digits

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, substr

I have a result of a query and am supposed to get the final digits of one column say 'term'

```
The value of column term can be like:
'term'     'number' (output)
---------------------------
xyz012         12
xyz112         112
xyz1           1
xyz02          2
xyz002         2
xyz88          88
```

Note: Not limited to above scenario's but requirement being last 3 or less characters can be digit

Function I used: `to_number(substr(term.name,-3))`
(Initially I assumed the requirement as last 3 characters are always digit, But I was wrong)

I am using to_number because if last 3 digits are '012' then number should be '12'
But as one can see in some specific cases like 'xyz88', 'xyz1') would give a

> ORA-01722: invalid number

How can I achieve this using substr or regexp_substr ?

Did not explore regexp_substr much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `REGEXP_SUBSTR`,

```
select column_name, to_number(regexp_substr(column_name,'\d+$'))
 from table_name;
```

- \d matches digits. Along with +, it becomes a group with one or more digits.
- $ matches end of line.
- Putting it together, this regex extracts a group of digits at the end of a string.

More details [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/ap_posix.htm#g693775).

Demo [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/14943).

Comment: Thx.
It works, but just curious what exactly does the regEx '\d+$' Do.
I accepted answer of the person who gave solution first.

Comment: Thx, you rock!.
Your's is the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle has the function `regexp_instr()` which does what you want:

```
select term, cast(substr(term, 1-regexp_instr(reverse(term),'[^0-9]')) as int) as number
```

Comment: Thx. This works for me.
Though I have one question: Any advantage of using 'cast as int' instead of to_number, both do the same in this scenario.
So basically you reverse string find position of first non digit number, 1- <position> to get the no of last digits for substr, cool

Comment: @user1933888 . . . I don't think there is a difference.  I have a tendency to ANSI standard constructs (that work across databases), but the Oracle vernacular would be `to_number()`.

Comment: ok, thx for the explanation you guys are super cool.
Though in moral dilemma weather to accept your answer or that of 'Ramblin' Man' as his solution looks more elegant.

Answer (score -1):

```
select SUBSTRING(acc_no,len(acc_no)-1,len(acc_no)) from table_name;
```

Comment: Does not appear to handle multiple digits.

Comment: @Tordek how can this not provide an answer to the question when the answer quite clearly does provide an answer?

Comment: Code-only answers are auto-flagged as low quality and as such are discouraged on stackoverflow. In the future please embellish your answer with details and explain why it is a solution to the question. This helps other users.